# Sorting an ArrayList so that certain numbers go first, and the order is otherwise preserved

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

```
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<HSSFCell>> newTogether(ArrayList<ArrayList<HSSFCell>> sheetData) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<HSSFCell>> temporary = new ArrayList<ArrayList<HSSFCell>>();
    for(int i = 0; i < sheetData.size(); i++) {
        ArrayList<HSSFCell> list = sheetData.get(i);
        if (list.get(3).getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
            if(Integer.parseInt(list.get(3).getStringCellValue()) > 100) {
                temporary.add(list);
                sheetData.remove(i);
                i--;
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < sheetData.size(); i++) {
        ArrayList<HSSFCell> list = sheetData.get(i);
        temporary.add(list);
    }
    return temporary;
}
```

What I am trying to do with my code is have the 2D ArrayList take out any numbers greater than 100 and put them in the beginning of the ArrayList, while preserving the order of the remaining elements. However, this code just returns an ArrayList in the original order, and if I add a `println` to either `if`, I get nothing. Could someone point out what it is I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you added a `println` statement to see if the `if` branch is actually being taken?

Comment: Looks to me that the `if` statement is never executed. Are your sure that you need to take the `3`-rd element (remember this is the fourth column)...

Comment: I have, I should proabably add that to the question. If I add a `println` to either `if`, I get nothing. Do you have any idea what causes this, however? And yes, I am looking for the fourth column. It is a mix of integers and strings.

Comment: Have you tried adding a break point to the `if` line? I have a funny feeling the string isn't being parsed correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried putting a println in front of the first if to check what getStringCellValue() returns?

btw. since Collections.sort is guaranteed to be stable according to the API documentation, you could use that. Should be faster than your way of doing it.

That could look like this

```
private static boolean biggerThan100(ArrayList<HSSFCell> list) {
  return list.get(3).getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC &&
      (Integer.parseInt(list.get(3).getStringCellValue()) > 100);
}

public static ArrayList<ArrayList<HSSFCell>> newTogether(ArrayList<ArrayList<HSSFCell>> sheetData) {
  ArrayList<ArrayList<HSSFCell>> temp = new ArrayList<>(sheetData);
  Collections.sort(temp, new Comparator<ArrayList<HSSFCell>>() {
      public int compare(ArrayList<HSSFCell> a, ArrayList<HSSFCell> b) {
        if(biggerThan100(a) && !biggerThan100(b)) return -1;
        else if(biggerThan100(b) && !biggerThan100(a)) return 1;
        else return 0;
      }
  });
  return temp;
}
```

Comment: Oddly enough, they all return 1 (CELL_TYPE_STRING) despite most being integers. I'll have to look at that. I can't use Java 8 on the computers at my school, the county won't update beyond Java 6. And wouldn't Collections.sort sort it like 26, 281, 34?

Comment: I changed my code to work with Java 6. And Collections.sort sorts the list in the way the Comparator object tells it to. In this case it will put all the lists at the start that have a number bigger 100 at position 3 and it will leave the order unchanged otherwise.